# How to use templates to call function based on data type?

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm working on an Arduino library where some methods will have to behave differently if a float is passed instead of an integer value. It has to be this way since the underlying function has to do more mathematical operations if a float is passed rather than an integer.

Here's some isolated, stripped down code to demonstrate the problem.

```c
void printdata(uint32_t data) 
{
  Serial.printf("Printing unsigned integer %d", data);
}

void printdata(float data) 
{
  Serial.printf("Printing float %i", data);
}

template<typename Data>
void myTemplate(const Data& d)
{
  printdata(d);
}
```

I'd like the template function to call printdata(uint32_t) if pass an integer number (such as `printdata(1000)`). I'd also like the template function to call printdata(float) when a float is passed (such as `printdata(10.00)`).

However, when I call `printdata(1000)` my compiler gives me an error saying `call of overloaded 'printdata(const double&)' is ambiguous`.

Can this be achieved without having to manually cast everything? I want the library I'm writing to be as user-friendly and less verbose as possible. Manually casting everything isn't really a great solution for me.

Thanks!

Comment: You're not showing the complete error message, nor the invocation of `myTemplate` that (I assume) is causing the error message.

Comment: Keep in mind that 10.00 is not a float, it's a double. 10.00f is a float.

Answer (score 1):

Consider `std::is_integral` from the `<type_traits>` header and also C++17 `constexpr if`.

`std::is_integral` will tell you if a given type is an integral type at compile time.

`constexpr if` is basically an if statement that is evaluated at compile time. The branch not taken is never executed (in fact it's not even compiled).

```
#include <type_traits>

void printdata(uint32_t data)
{
    Serial.printf("Printing unsigned integer %d", data);
}

void printdata(float data)
{
    Serial.printf("Printing float %i", data);
}

template<typename Data>
void myTemplate(const Data& d)
{
    // uses C++17 constexpr if
    if constexpr (std::is_integral_v<Data>) printdata(static_cast<uint32_t>(d));
    else printdata(static_cast<float>(d));
}
```

**EDIT:** However, if you can't use C++17 you will need to use fancier template logic, which I'll demonstrate next. I'll also avoid using anything from the `type_traits` header because you mentioned you don't have access to it for some reason?

**NOTE:** The code I'm about to show is very gross and I would never recommend writing it outside of academic exercises or curiosity. The reason for this is the lack of the `type_traits` header, which means we have to define much more than we would otherwise have to with e.g. SFINAE. Additionally, most template code uses lots of `type_traits` stuff, which makes this even more awkward.

So at this point (without the `type_traits` header or C++17), **I would suggest not using templates and simply make overloads for every type you want to use** `printdata` with, which avoids the issue of ambiguous overloads.

```
// given a type T, defines a static member function called f that routes to the correct form of printdata.
// default implementation goes to int version.
template<typename T> struct _get_version { static void f(T val) { printdata(static_cast<uint32_t>(val)); } };

// specialize this for all the floating point types (float, double, and long double).
template<> struct _get_version<float> { static void f(float val) { printdata(static_cast<float>(val)); } };
template<> struct _get_version<double> { static void f(double val) { printdata(static_cast<float>(val)); } };
template<> struct _get_version<long double> { static void f(long double val) { printdata(static_cast<float>(val)); } };

template<typename Data>
void myTemplate(Data d)
{
    // get the version Data should use, then use its internal f function
    _get_version<Data>::f(d);
}
```

Comment: Suppose `d` is a `double` (or perhaps a `long long`).  This solution breaks then (supposing that an overload for, say, `printdata (double)` exists).

Comment: @PaulSanders Ah, well OP didn't mention that might be an issue. In this case there could be another `constexpr if` using `std::is_same` for any special cases.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that every time you add a new overload to `printdata` you also have to modify the template.  It would not be my choice.

Comment: @PaulSanders Again, OP didn't say there might ever be other `printdata` functions. But if we're being technical, OP writing this as a template in the first place implies that there's a generic pattern to what each instantiation should do. You seem to be proposing something that's not generic and thus shouldn't even be a template anyway. It seems like you'd just prefer function overloading.

Comment: It turns out that the version of avr-gcc shipped with the Arduino IDE only supports C++11. This means `if constexpr` won't work. I also get an error when trying to include type_traits. It seems like I can't use `typeid` either, since Runtime Type Information (RTTI) is disabled by default.

Comment: @MCUdude The lack of `type_traits` header is unfortunate (it's a C++11 header, so idk why it would be missing). Regardless, I'll add code for an alternative that doesn't require any of that. One sec.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes we have to provide additional overloads to disambiguate between options. In this case, we'd provide additional overloads for `printdata`.

The best option is to just add additional `printdata` functions for `int`s, `double`s, and other datatypes you care about, but if you're fine printing them with as `unsigned int`s and `float`s, you can just cast them.

```
void printdata(uint32_t data) 
{
  Serial.printf("Printing unsigned integer %d", data);
}

// ints should be printed as unsigned ints?
void printdata(int data) {
  printdata((uint32_t)data); //Call unsigned version
}

void printdata(float data) 
{
  Serial.printf("Printing float %i", data);
}

//doubles should be printed as floats
void printdata(double data)
{
  printdata((float)data);
}
```

Comment: This is definitely the easiest approach. However, I will have to this to many functions in the library. If possible I'd like to do this (automatic casting?) with templates. If it turns out it is not possible with templates, this will be the way to go.

Comment: Correct me if I’m wrong, but what you want to do is output “Printing [typename] [value]”?

Comment: In other words you want to write printdata as a template?

Comment: I do not want to write printdata as a template. I need them to be separate functions. This is because in the "real" code a mathematic operation is done differently (multiplications and bit shifts) if a float is passed rather than an integer.

I've simplified the code in this example to isolate the issue as much as possible.